# Microsoft Bot Framework Web Chat

Tags: bots

I have created a bot that is going to sit on a public website. At the moment, I am simply pasting the iframe snippet with the Secret key that was generated by the bot framework on to the page. I am a bit concerned about making the secret key public. I understand that any developer will be able to embed the bot anywhere they like. What else can they do with the secret key? Are they able to use the secret key to view other conversations with users?
What are all the advantages of using the token instead.

I have read through the following documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/channel-connect-webchat

Thanks!